# Javascript RegExp parsing IRC color codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to parse IRC color codes in the format `\u00030` to `\u000315`.
I added all RGB colors to a table, and looping through them I with this:

```
console.log(i + ">" + '\\u0003'+i + ">" + colors[i]);
var re = new RegExp("\\u0003"+i, 'gi');
console.log(re + " > " + '</span><span style="color:' + colors[i]+ ';">');
```

I get this output:

```
tools.php:337 15>\u000315>rgb(210,210,210)
tools.php:339 /\u000315/gi > </span><span style="color:rgb(210,210,210);"> 
tools.php:337 14>\u000314>rgb(127,127,127)
tools.php:339 /\u000314/gi > </span><span style="color:rgb(127,127,127);"> 
tools.php:337 13>\u000313>rgb(255,0,255)
tools.php:339 /\u000313/gi > </span><span style="color:rgb(255,0,255);"> 
tools.php:337 12>\u000312>rgb(0,0,252)
```

And nothing changes when I do `html.replace(re, "<span stuff>");`

Hardcoding it down to `html.replace(/\\u00314/gi, '</span><span style="color: rgb(127,127,127);">');` produces no results either..

The stuff I'm trying to parse:

```
\u0002\u000314:: \u00037Channel Name \u000314:: \u00030SITE: \u00034UP \u000314:: \u00030IRC BONUS: \u00034OFFLINE \u000314:: \u00030SIGNUPS: \u00034CLOSED \u000314::\u000f
```

I seem to be missing something. `\u` or `\\u` makes no difference, `gi`, `g`, `i` or none makes no difference, and all in all it seems like it's simply not parsing anything this way.

The thing I did find out is that if I drop the RegExp and thus the modifiers for just `html.replace("\\u00314", '</span><span style="color: rgb(127,127,127);">');` it replaces the first occurence, but that's not enough.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: `html.replace("\\u00314"g, '`

Comment: Are you doing html = html.replace(...) ?

Comment: Yes I am @aaron_world_traveler

@RokoC.Buljan that doesn't solve it, I still can't do `html.replace("\\u0003"+i+""g, '</span><span style="color:' + colors[i]+ ';"> ');` that way

Answer (score 1):

What worked in the end is the code below. Saving the string to a variable rather than doing the `+i` in the function is what worked

```
            var val = $('textarea#topic').val();
            var html = "<span style=\"color: #fff;\">" + val + "</span>";
            var colors = [
                "rgb(0,147,0)",
                "rgb(0,0,0)",
                "rgb(0,0,127)",
                "rgb(0,147,0)",
                "rgb(255,0,0)",
                "rgb(127,0,0)",
                "rgb(156,0,156)",
                "rgb(252,127,0)",
                "rgb(255,255,0)",
                "rgb(0,252,0)",
                "rgb(0,147,147)",
                "rgb(0,255,255)",
                "rgb(0,0,252)",
                "rgb(255,0,255)",
                "rgb(127,127,127)",
                "rgb(210,210,210)"
            ];
            for(i = (colors.length-1); i >= 0; i--) {
                var index = 0;
                var str = "\\u0003"+i+"";
                while((index = html.indexOf(str, index + 1)) > -1) {
                    html = html.replace(str, '</span><span style="color:' + colors[i]+ ';">');
                    console.log(str + ">" + colors[i]);
                }
                $('div#topictext').html(html);
                done = false;
                setTimeout(setTrue(), 5000);
                while(!done) {
                }
            }
            html = html.replace("\\u0002", "");
            html = html.replace("\\u000f", "");
            $('div#topictext').html(html);
```